# How to replace content after a container

Tags: jquery, html

I have a container as shown below

```
<div class="container>
</div>
```

The intention is to add content below the container div. I use the JQuery command '.after'

```
$('.container').after('Content A')
```

to get the following result

```
<div class="container>
</div>
Content A
```

My question is, how can I replace 'Content A' with 'Content B'? I tried to use the same '.after' command

```
$('.container').after('Content B')
```

but I got the following result (which is not what I want)

```
<div class="container>
</div>
Content B
Content A
```

So how can I remove 'Content A' and just add 'Content B'?

Comment: do you want to remove everything after </div> ?

Comment: you can use the nextUntill() [here](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) is the manual.

Comment: @punit - jQuery's `.nextUntil()` will skip over plain text nodes so you can't get the text node as shown here that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your new content in a div so you can target it:

```
$('.container').after('<div class="afterContent">Content A</div>');
```

Then, to replace it:

```
$('.afterContent').html('Content B');
```

It is also possible using plain javascript (not using jQuery) to target just the text node that you inserted the first time and change it's text, but encapsulating it in a div as I've shown makes it much easier.

If you want to see how to modify the text node directly when it's not wrapped in any other type of object, you can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/BTrrD/.  I wouldn't recommend doing it this way (it's the hard way to solve your problem), but I included it for completeness.

Comment: what happens if I have a list of '.container's? How do I know which #afterContent to replace the html with?

Comment: you need to jump over that container using it's index.

Comment: I modified my answer so it will work with multiple containers, but the way you have it set up it will put the same content after all containers.  If you want different content after different containers, then you have to be able to separately target each one somehow (with an id or some other identifying info).